# Unicode text file to Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode

I am trying to read a Unicode text file and to put it in a Python dictionary,
but after reading it dictionary methods such as `haskey` `get` `set` are not working.

This is the sample file I am reading from:

```
എല്ലാ
പുതിയ

കാറുകളില ും
സുരക്ഷാസംവിധാന ങ്ങളായ
എയര്‍ ബാഗു ം
ആന്റി ലേ ാ ക്ക്
ബ്രേക്ക ിങ്
സിസ്റ്റ വും
നിര്‍ബന്ധമാക്കി യേ ക്കും .
അടുത്തവര്‍ഷ ം
ഒക് ടേ ാ ബറി ന്
മുമ്പ ായി
നിയമ ം
നടപ്പാക്കാനാ ണ്
കേന്ദ്ര സര്‍ക്കാരിന്റെ
തീരുമാന ം .
```

This is my code:

```
newDict= {}
with open('dictonary_mal.txt', 'r') as f :
    for line in f:
        splitLine = line.split()
        newDict[splitLine[0]] = ",".join(splitLine[1:])
```

Any clue what is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that line 3 is an empty line, splitting it will just give 1 item.

This has nothing to do with unicode :)

Try this instead:

```
newDict= {}
with open('dictonary_mal.txt', 'r') as f :
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            splitLine = line.split()
            newDict[splitLine[0]] = ",".join(splitLine[1:])
```

Comment: @karu: `line.split()` will split by whitespace. There isn't any non-whitespace there so there is nothing to return.

Comment: Okay, How to fix it ?

Comment: ",".join(splitLine[1:]) -- This line of code will take value after the 2nd value in the list, but in the 3rd line, you just have a space. Now when you do a split, you end up with one member in the list and hence it throws a "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: @nEO: it's actually not the `splitline[1:]` since that always works. It's the `splitLine[0]` that doesn't exist when simply given whitespace. Try this in the console: `'\n'.split()`

Comment: Yeah. Got it. I missed that part. splitLine[0] doesn't exist. Thanks

Comment: oops that stopping my computer